# How do I replace all "unsigned long" in my project files with "unsigned long long" without affecting compiler system files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

I need to replace all occurences of "unsigned long" with "unsigned long long" in my solution.

I need to replacement it only in my own files.

Files like "string.h" etc. should not be affected.
How can I make sure that no system / compiler files are affected?

When I press Ctrl + F, a box opens up which allows me to select either

```
Current Block 
Current Document
All Open Documents
Current Project
Entire Solution
```

I have already managed to wreck up string.h and other files, so "Entire Solution" is obviously not the correct choice.

Thank you!

Comment: At a guess, don;t open any MS headers, open all your files  and then All Open documents. Or better, use a command line tool such as sed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now opened each and every one of my files manually and used "Only this document".